# В Ресурсе не изменяется\сохраняется TV-поле

Tags: php, cms, modx

Доброго времени суток.

В админке ModX в ресурсе пытаюсь изменить значение TV поля:
[image: tv-image]

ввожу новое значение, сохраняю ресурс - ресурс сохраняется, но при перезагрузке страницы - поле остается прежним, как и было до изменения. Сам ресурс при этом редактируется корректно. Остальные поля изменяются как надо.

При этом в логах modX вижу ошибку, связанную с моей попыткой поменять это поле:

[image: log-error]

/home/bpskby/public_html/core/model/phpthumb/phpthumb.class.php

PHP warning: getimagesize(/home/bpskby/public_html/Какие требования предъявляются к опалубке): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Однако, эта ошибка не вылазит при повторных попытках редактировать это TV-поле, просто один раз выбило и я вижу ее в логе.

В самом файле, указанном в этом логе я вижу **следующее**:
[image: file-php]

Что делать дальше с этой информацией - не приходит в голову)
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Сайт на MODX Revolution 2.8.1-pl

Версия Apache:  2.4.54

Версия PHP: 7.4.33

Версия MySQL:   5.7.40-cll-lve

Comment: Вот какие вещи пробовал и которые не сработали:

Пытался изменить тип ТВ поля на текст, и изменить содержимое ресурса.
Отключал ТВ поле и включал.
Удалял содержимое поля оставляя пустым содержимое.
Выбирал изображение через галерею менеджера файлов.

Answer (score 0):

У вас как я погляжу поле для изображения, верно? Вы ведь изображение вставляете, да? Если да, попробуйте изменить название картинки - чтобы как минимум без пробелов было.

> getimagesize(/home/bpskby/public_html/Какие требования предъявляются к опалубке):

функция `getimagesize()` ожидает изображение, и не найдя его, справедливо ругается.

Comment: Дело в том, что этот текст уже был здесь до меня, и вот как раз проблема в том, что я его не могу изменить вообще ни на что)
Даже пустое поле без содержимого не сохраняется.
Пробовал вставлять сразу изображение выбирая в файловом менеджере картинку - не работает.

Так же пробовал ручками прописывать эти же пути к картинкам - не работает.

Comment: В консоли браузера у вас нет ошибок? я видел пару раз, когда поле с типом Изображение не работало как надо. Что могу предложить -если есть ошибка в консоли -найти её причину. Также можно попробовать создать другое TV изображение, будет ли оно работать? Ну и возможно обновление до 2.8.2-2.8.4 поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему.

Суть была в том, что в базе данных у таблицы с TV-полями (site_tmplvars) послетали автоинкременты для ID столбцов, и TV поля с контентом который редактировался, его id становился = 0 в своих таблицах (site_tmplvar_contentvalues), и новые TV поля так же при создании имели нулевой айди в своих таблицах (site_tmplvars). Пришлось править ручками таблицы с TV полями, имеющие нулевое айди и  контент у которых был заполнен чем-либо.

Затем для таблицы TV-полей (**site_tmplvars**) и таблицы контента TV-полей (**site_tmplvar_contentvalues**) в столбец ID  пришлось ручками проставить primary_key и включать автоинкремент.